# Displaying Database information into a New Activity class, Android, PHP, SQL

Tags: php, android, sql, database, android-activity

I was developing an Android Application with Login and Registration features. I got a very good start from the tutorials and example from this site: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/
However, the tutorials only shows how to insert data into database, for example the registration, but did not show how to display them in a new page. Lets say I wanted to display my login information such as name and email based on this tutorial, into TextView or Button format in a new activity. What coding should I implement to the mainActivity class to get the data from database. I looked into other tutorials but their methods are different, some combine the JSONParser and Databasehandler class together, some separate them into different classes like this one. Please help I've been trying for very long already, thank you very much.

Here's what I got from my xml and activity class, please assist me.

XML Class

```
<!-- Display user info Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/displayInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:textColor="#21dbd4"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
```

Activity class

```
package com.example.trafficmaster;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.trafficmaster.library.DatabaseHandler2;
import com.example.trafficmaster.library.UserFunctions;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    //JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //Set View to home.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.home);


            TextView displayInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayInfo);

            //connect to database
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = ...................
            displayInfo.setText(............);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this: 
http://ugirusgiarto.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/json-php-mysql-with-asynctask-progressdialog/ 
If you make this in AsyncTask, the queries will not interfere with the interface. Otherwise, the interface will become "slow".